# Is there a way to use prepend with Shopify's language translation?

Tags: shopify, liquid, prepend, language-translation

'Currently I want to display View All "Collection Title". I do this successfully using the prepend. However, when creating a shopify theme one of the requirements is language support / translation.

```
<div class="collection-cta">{{ product_collection.title | prepend: 'View All ' | link_to: product_collection.url }}</div>
```

I am having trouble figuring how how to prepend the shopify translation markup.

```
{{ 'collections.general.view_all' | t }}
```

This outputs the View All text translation correctly, but getting to work inside of prepend:'' has proven to be problematic. I haven't been able to find strong documentation on this so any perspective would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
<a href="{{product_collection.url }}">{{product_collection.title}} {{ 'collections.general.view_all' | t }}</a>
```

No need to use link_to... I'm not entirely clear on the inner workings of liquid, but it does expect a certain number of arguments... adding prepend and the translation tag may have thrown it.

So split it all out - and it should work.

Comment: That did the trick. Good suggestion. The code above was missing an ' for the language translation bit. I left it off on accident on the original post. So I reposted the working code below.

`<a href="{{product_collection.url }}">{{product_collection.title}} {{ 'collections.general.view_all' | t }}</a>`

Comment: You're right - my fat fingers :) have corrected the typo in the answer. cheers :)